# jsoup tag parsing with table

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

How can i separate every letter in that table? A and B must not be together.

```
Document  doc = Jsoup.connect(getURL).timeout(0).get(); 
Elements getdata= doc.select("tr[bgcolor] td");
for (Element element : getdata) {
         System.out.println(element.text());   
         // it gives A and B together.
        }

<tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
  <td>A
    <br> B
  </td>
  <td>C
    <br> D
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried? Jsoup gives you all of the information you need, where are you running into trouble?

Comment: (After the edit) *"A and B must not be together."* Well...they aren't, so mission accomplished.

Comment: I added code sample.Is it possible to separate <br> tagged text there ?@T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> Is it possible to separate `<br>` tagged text there?

Yes, via [`Node#childNodes`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes%28%29), which will give you a text node, then the `br` element, then another text node.

Or if you like, you can do it via `element.html().split("<br>")`, but probably better to use `childNodes`.